Apache Airflow: Could not read served logs: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
I deployed my Airflow Instance on Heroku. But I'm not able to see any logs for my DAG tasks.
The only thing I can see in the log section is:
Could not read served logs: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
This is my airflow.cfg folder:
[logging]
# The directory to place log files
base_log_folder = /app/logs

# Log folder for processor logs
processor_log_folder = /app/logs/scheduler

# Whether to enable remote logging
remote_logging = False


All My DAG functions just use print statements and not the python logging lib. I don't think this could be the problem as I've used print statements on cloud hosted airflow before. What am I doing wrong?
